# How to draw emf/wmf image in GDI+ with alpha blending?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I use [GDI+ Graphics.DrawImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/ms536056(v=vs.85).aspx) method to draw metafile images (emf/wmf) in my application. This method allows set color matrix by `ImageAttributes`. I use color matrix to perform image alpha blending (drawing semi transparent image) like this:

```
const auto alphaPercent = 0.5f
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = { 
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, alphaPercent, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

ImageAttributes imageAttributes;
imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(&colorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlagsDefault, ColorAdjustTypeDefault);

pGraphics->DrawImage(pImageToDraw,imagePosition, 0.f, 0.f, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, UnitPixel, &imageAttributes);
```

This method excellent works for bitmaps but not for emf metafiles.
Changing `ColorAdjustTypeDefault` to `ColorAdjustTypePen` or `ColorAdjustTypeBrush` doesn't help.

**Example**: *GDI+ result:*
[image]

*But should be (alpha = 50%):*
[image]

How to draw metafile image in GDI+ with alpha blending ?

Comment: Show the rest of the code, also expand on "it is not working...", it's showing what?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, "it's showing what?" It shows metafile image without applying color matrix.

Comment: The WMF format is ancient and strongly tied to GDI.  Which never supported more than 24bpp pixel formats.  GDI+ fixed that, but without a change to WMF.  Consider rendering it to a bitmap and painting that bitmap with that ColorMatrix.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2b4c5c41-8f3c-4e81-9169-78082b80c747/gdic-transition-between-two-images?forum=winforms

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. I hoped there is other way :(

Comment: Everything works fine if initial image is EMF+ (not legacy WMF or EMF). So i hope just enough to convert WMF\EMF to EMF+ format (see [Metafile::ConvertToEmfPlus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-metafile-converttoemfplus(inconstgraphics_inconstwchar_inoutint_inemftype_inconstwchar))).